# Switching Channels & Combining Applications

Tags: webrtc, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

Can I seamlessly switch between a video call and Interactive Video Streaming channels?

I want to create a watch party where a small group of users can see each other. But, then call a user up from that video call into the IVS section group.

Answer (score 0):

When using the Agora Web SDK you could initialize multiple client objects to subscribe to multiple channels (*one live stream and one video chat*). Make sure when you initialize each client, you add the event listeners before joining the channel. Even if you aren't using both channels at once, you can quickly join and leave from the individual client objects with minimal latency.

Something to note when you have lots of streams streams/videos playing at one time it can be very CPU/GPU intensive, so you might want to use [Dual Stream mode](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/iagorartcclient.html#enabledualstream) to have a high quality and lower quality stream.